# how to give state DateTime text as string?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

```
if (reader["LastCheck"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    job.LastCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["LastCheck"]);
}
else
{                         
    job.LastCheck = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I want to give out some string message if its null value in DB. LastChange is a DateTime and its impossible to write state it some text.  How to do that??
something like this but working:

```
else
{
    job.LastCheck =  "DB doent have a value!";
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify this: "...its impossible to write state it some text."

Comment: From what you have posted, it looks like the job.LastCheck is assigned as a DateTime. So you wouldn't be able to put text into it.

Comment: is LastCheck a DateTime type?  If so, you cannot set it to a String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign a string to a DateTime.

You can convert LastCheck to a nullable DateTime.

```
public DateTime? LastCheck { get; set; }
```

Then change your code to be

```
else
{
  job.LastCheck =  null;
}
```

And when it comes time to display your DateTime to the user,

```
if(!job.LastCheck.HasValue)
    // display your "DB doesn't have a value!" string here
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can change the type of `LastCheck` to `DateTime?` which will make it nullable, ie you can assign null to it - or you set it to DateTime.MinValue

Then in your presentation, you can check for `null` or `MinValue` if you chose that approach.

Something like this:

```
if(job.LastCheck == null)
```

or

```
if(job.LastCheck == DateTime.MinValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already agree that what you are trying to do is not possible.

Options:

1) You can make "LastCheck" a string property. And store dataTime.ToString() or your message in that variable. And then user can use DateTime.TryParse(), and if it fails he will have your message.

2) [which i would recommend] Create a placeholder class for your DateTime and the Message.

```
pulbic class LastCheckInfo{
public DateTime LastCheck{get;set;}
public string ErrorMessage{get;set;}
}
```

Now, you can populate an instance of this class. And your user would check for "ErrorMessage" to be empty or null before reading a valid date.

```
public LastCheckInfo GetLastCheckInfo(...){
if (reader["LastCheck"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    return new LastCheckInfo(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["LastCheck"], "");
}
else
{                         
    return new LastCheckInfo(DateTime.Min, "Failed to parse/get LastCheck Date") ;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible, but if you are going to post in on the view, you can do this. Might not be the best answer for you but I hope this will give you the idea for a work around.

```
<%
if (reader["LastCheck"] != DBNull.Value)
{
%>
    <%= Convert.ToDateTime(reader["LastCheck"]) %>
<%
}
else
{
%>                         
    <%="DB doent have a value!" %>
<%
}
%>
```